# PHP Xpath Case Insensitive Query With Node Attribute Value

Tags: php, xml, xpath, case-insensitive

I am working with a PHP script to read a Restful XML feed.
In selecting a User node, I need to set the comparison to case insensitive; however, I have been unable to find the exact syntax for my particular scenario.
The code does seem to be working; however, if someone could run a line over my case-insensitivity code, I'd be most appreciative.
Thanks for any leads as to potential improvements in the code.

XML code ('test_a.xml'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Users xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dmu="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/user-metadata">
    <User username="john-smith" dmu:userId="14" SecondaryID="jsmith" enabled="false">
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>L</MiddleName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <Email>john-smith@email.com</Email>
        <LocalAuthentication/>
        <Item xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="/login/service/v4/User/USERNAME:john-smith"/>
    </User>
    <User username="mary-smith" dmu:userId="19" SecondaryID="MSMITH">
        <FirstName>Mary</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
        <Email>mary-smith@email.com</Email>
        <LocalAuthentication/>
        <Item xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="/login/service/v4/User/USERNAME:mary-smith"/>
    </User>   
</Users>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$test_var = 'msmith'; //sample input lowercase
//$test_var = 'MSMITH'; //sample input uppercase
$secondary_user_id = strtolower($test_var); //to lowercase for comparison in user node, below.

$url_bio_report = "test_a.xml";
$xml_bio_report = simplexml_load_file($url_bio_report);
$xml_bio_report->registerXPathNamespace('xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
$xml_bio_report->registerXPathNamespace('dmu','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/user-metadata');

//below - original xpath query
//$xml_bio_report_abbrev = $xml_bio_report->xpath('//User[@SecondaryID="'.$secondary_user_id.'"]');

//below - attempt for case insensitivity
$xml_bio_report_abbrev = $xml_bio_report->xpath('//User[contains(translate(@SecondaryID,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"),"'.$secondary_user_id.'")]');

$str_user_exists='';
if ($xml_bio_report_abbrev){
    $user_name = $xml_bio_report_abbrev[0]['username'];
    echo '<br>'.$user_name;
    $secondary_id = $xml_bio_report_abbrev[0]['SecondaryID'];
    echo '<br>'.$secondary_id;
    $str_user_exists = 'true'; //
    echo '<br>'.$str_user_exists;
} else {
    $str_user_exists = 'false'; //
    echo '<br>'.$str_user_exists;
}
?>
```

Comment: Noticed that your code seems to be missing the load the load, if you add - `$xml_bio_report = simplexml_load_file($url_bio_report);` it outputs - `<br>mary-smith<br>MSMITH<br>true`

Comment: sorry - I mistakenly left out a line of code when I was posting here.  It is now complete.  Thanks for the catch. :)